# Create a bin for anything above X value in GGPlot2 Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Using `ggplot2`, I want to create a histogram where anything above X is grouped into the final bin.  For example, if most of my distribution was between 100 and 200, and I wanted to bin by 10, I would want anything above 200 to be binned in "200+".

```
# create some fake data    
id <- sample(1:100000, 10000, rep=T)
visits <- sample(1:1200,10000, rep=T)

#merge to create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(cbind(id,visits))

#plot the data
hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=visits)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=50)
```

How can I limit the X axis, while still representing the data I want limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the `breaks` argument for `geom_histogram`:

```
# create some fake data    
id <- sample(1:100000, 10000, rep=T)
visits <- sample(1:1200,10000, rep=T)

#merge to create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(cbind(id,visits))

#plot the data
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=visits)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(seq(0, 200, by=10), max(visits)), position = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,210))
```

This would look like this (with the caveats that the fake data looks pretty bad here and the axis need to be adjusted as well to match the breaks):

[image: manual breaks on histogram]

**Edit:**

Maybe someone else can weigh in here:

```
# create breaks and labels
brks <- c(seq(0, 200, by=10), max(visits))
lbls <- c(as.character(seq(0, 190, by=10)), "200+", "")
# true
length(brks)==length(lbls)

# hmmm
ggplot(df, aes(x=visits)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=brks, position = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,220)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=lbls)
```

The plot errors with:

```
Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale) : 
  Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

Which looks like [this](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/261) but that was fixed 8 months ago.

Comment: That's just about spot on.  How would you update the x-axis labels if I wanted to add something like "200+".

Comment: I think via `scale_x_continuous(labels=...)` but I'm not quite sure

Comment: The error about unequal length of scales and labels goes away if you tell scale_x_continous what the breaks are, and don't rely on the scale to notice the breaks from geom_histogram:  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 200, by = 10), max(visits)), labels=lbls)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to fudge it a little to get around the issues of bin labelling then just subset your data and create the binned values in a new sacrificial data-frame:

```
id <- sample(1:100000, 10000, rep=T)
visits <- sample(1:1200,10000, rep=T)

#merge to create a dataframe
df <- data.frame(cbind(id,visits))
#create sacrificical data frame
dfsac <- df
dfsac$visits[dfsac$visits > 200 ] <- 200
```

Then use the `breaks` command in `scale_x_continuous` to define your bin labels easily:

```
ggplot(data=dfsac, aes(dfsac$visits)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(seq(0, 200, by=10)), 
                 col="black", 
                 fill="red") +
  labs(x="Visits", y="Count")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 200), breaks=c(seq(0, 200, by=10)), labels=c(seq(0,190, by=10), "200+"))
```

[image]

Comment: The label 200+ should be centred in the middle of the final bar.